# pascal Напишите программу подсчета количества элементов этого массива, имеющих максимальное значение

Tags: pascal

Дан массив из десяти целых чисел. Напишите программу подсчета количества элементов этого массива, имеющих максимальное значение.

Comment: Написал. Ждем дальнейших указаний.

Comment: приведите пожалуйста код ваших попыток решить данное задание, и тогда вам гарантированно помогут, в противном случае вопрос будет закрыт из-за несоответствия (правила форума)

Answer (score 1):

В принципе это стандартная задача

```
program test;
const N=10;
var a:array[1..10] of integer;
    i,ma,k:integer;

begin
 for i:=1 to N do begin
  a[i]:=-2+random(4);
  write(a[i],' ');
 end;
 writeln;
 k:=1;
 ma:=a[1];
 for i:=2 to N do begin
  if a[i]=ma then k:=k+1
  else
    if a[i]>ma then
      begin
        ma:=a[i];
        k:=1;
      end;
 end;
 writeln(k);
end.
```